# How to create checkboxes with the values of model instances created by users

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to create forms with checkboxes in them which values of these checkboxes is a model instance created by users.
Here is my SessionModel:

```
class SessionModel(models.Model):
starting_time = models.TimeField()
.
.
```

Imagine that I have several instances of this model with various starting_times.
and I have another model which is:

```
class TimeModel(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField()
```

now i want to select the required instances of SessionModel and update them.
But the problem is that I want to have a form with checkboxes with the values of TimeModel.time to grab the instances in SessionModel with the starting_time same as selected TimeModel.time but I don't know how to create these checkboxes should I use dynamic forms or is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Django, and if I've understood the question right, this is a two-step process. First, process a form to select a time or TimeModel. Then process a form to select SessionModel(s) from a queryset filtered  on the value returned from the first form.

An alternative would be a Javascript client-side solution, where you would send  unfiltered SessionModel data to the client, along with the TimeModel-based buttons for filtering, and a Javascript that hides the SessionModel choices unless the relevant TimeModel button is selected. Definitely more work.

You might also find the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package useful. It can often unify such operations into a single view, although there are still (at least) two interactions with the server.